# Unable to disable numerical sorting in File Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry

I have tried following this tutorial to turn off numerical (or logical) sorting in Windows File Explorer:

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/91417-enable-disable-numerical-sorting-file-explorer-windows-10-a.html

But whenever I reboot and go to the directory in question, the files are still sorted numerically! I have Windows 10 Home so cannot access Group Policy Editor. So I have been editing the registry.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Created by: Shawn Brink
; Created on: August 14th 2017
; Tutorial: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/91417-enable-disable-numerical-sorting-file-explorer-windows-10-a.html


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoStrCmpLogical"=dword:00000001
```

What else do I need to do?

[ed]

I have three files:

```
a210.dat
a400.dat
a2339.dat
```

With numerical sorting disabled this is the incorrect order.

Comment: Numbers will always list first before files starting with A, ... That is how Windows Explorer sorts alphabetically.

Comment: Updated my question to clarify.

Comment: I just duplicated your sort, and I believe a2339.dat comes at the end (me as well) is because the filename is longer after the initial "a"

Comment: That should not matter at all. Only the alphabetical order, beginning from the left, should matter.

Comment: I have seen this on all my own systems so I am quite sure that is the way Windows 10 File Explorer works.

Comment: It is a tech support question.

Answer (score 0):

It's still working for me.

At the mimimun, the shell needs to be restarted for the policy to take effect -- sign off, shutdown, and restart are also ootions.

- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`

NoStrCmpLogical = 0

[image]

NoStrCmpLogical = 1

[image]

On Windows 10 Home here as well,but haven't upped to 20H2 yet...

[image]

Comment: I don't know what version I was on when I asked the question yesterday, but I just updated to 21H1 and the problem did not go away. It could be anything, dunno. Thanks for helping, though.

Comment: Did you verify the creation of the value by viewing in RegEdit? Did you check behavior in Safe MOde?